# SPARK processing of polymorphic JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

Consider this JSON input (shown in multiline form for readability but the actual input docs are one-line CR-delimited):

```
{
  "common": { "type":"A", "date":"2020-01-01T12:00:00" },
  "data": {
    "name":"Dave",
    "pets": [ "dog", "cat" ]
  }
}
{
  "common": { "type": "B", "date":"2020-01-01T12:00:00" },
  "data": {
    "whatever": { "X": {"foo":3}, "Y":"bar" },
    "favoriteInts": [ 0, 1, 7]
  }
}
```

I am familiar with `json-schema` and the way I can describe that the `data`
substructure can be either `name,pets` *OR* `whatever,favoriteInts`.  We
use the `common.type` field to runtime identify the type.

**Is this possible in SPARK schema definition?**  Initial experiments along the lines of:

```
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("common", StructType(common_schema)), # .. because the type is consistent                                       
        StructField("data", StructType())  # attempting to declare a "generic" struct
    ])
    df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(source, schema)
```

does not work; upon read where the `data` struct contains, well, anything but in this particular example 2 fields, we get:

```
+--------------------+----+                                                     
|              common|data|
+--------------------+----+
|{2020-01-01T12:00...|  {}|
+--------------------+----+
```

and trying to extract any named field yields `No such struct field <whatever>`. Leaving the "generic struct" out of the `schema` def entirely yields a dataframe without *any* field named `data`, never mind the fields within.

Beyond this, I ultimately seek to do something  like this:

```
df = spark.read.json(source)

def processA(frame):
    frame.select( frame.data.name )  # we KNOW name exists for type A
    ...

def processB(frame):
    frame.select( frame.data.favoriteInts )  # we KNOW favoriteInts exists for type B
    ...

processA( df.filter(df.common.type == "A") )
processB( df.filter(df.common.type == "B") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use nested and nullable types (by specifying `True`) in the struct to accommodate for the uncertainty.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, ArrayType, StructField, IntegerType

data_schema = StructType([
    # Type A related attributes
    StructField("name",StringType(),True), # True implies nullable
    StructField("pets",ArrayType(StringType()),True),

   # Type B related attributes
    StructField("whatever",StructType([
        StructField("X",StructType([
            StructField("foo",IntegerType(),True)
        ]),True),
        StructField("Y",StringType(),True)
    ]),True), # True implies nullable
    StructField("favoriteInts",ArrayType(IntegerType()),True),
])
schema = StructType([
        StructField("common", StructType(common_schema)), # .. because the type is consistent                                       
        StructField("data", data_schema)  
])
```

Comment: Will try soon and plus-up if it meets needs; thx!

Comment: This works for most purposes.  The nuance is that peer field names in the different substructures must be of the same type.